# How to use awk or sed, add content before the last symbol} in the text

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

my file a.txt:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

I want to insert content just before} in the last line.

```
{}
{}
{content}
```

How to use sed or awk?

I started to try sed, but it will add content before} on each line.  This is the code:

```
sed -i "s/}$/content&/$g"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following `tac` + `awk` solution.

```
tac Input_file | awk 'FNR==1{sub(/}/,"content&")} 1' | tac
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `sed` + `tac` here.

```
tac Input_file | sed '1 s/}/content&/' | tac
```

Comment: If  the `}` is always on the last line for the 2nd solution, 2 reads of the file can be eliminated by `sed '$s/\/(.*\)}/content}/' file`.

Answer (score 1):

To run a command only for the last line in file, just add `$` in front of it.

```
sed "$s/}$/content&/g"
```

If the last `}` should be prefixed with something, but is not on the last line in file, we can hold the lines up from the last `}` and replace the `}` in hold space on the last line:

```
cat <<EOF |
{}
{}
{}
sometext
EOF
sed -n '
    # if the line contains }
    /}/{
        # if there is anything in hold space, print it
        x
        /^$/!p
        x
        # hold current line
        h
        # read next line
        b
    }
    # if the line does not contain }, hold it
    H
    # if this is the last line
    ${
        # take hold space
        x
        # replace the } with content}
        # there should be only one }
        s/}/content}/
        # print it
        p
    }
'
```

[on repl outputs](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SaltyPutridCybernetics):

```
{}
{}
{content}
sometext
```

So a oneliner: `sed -n '/}/{x;/^$/!p;x;h;b};H;${x; s/}/content}/ ;p}'`

Comment: This works fine with the example, bot of course won't work if the last match isn't also the very last line of the file.

Comment: Replace `"` with `'`. In `"` the `$s` will expand.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\(.*\)}/\1content}/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and insert `content` before the last `}`

Alternative, perhaps more memory efficient:

```
sed -n 'x;/}/{x;//{x;p;x;:a;h};//!H;$!b;x;s//content&/p;d};x;//ba;p' file
```

Use the hold space to store lines starting with a line containing a `}`. If the hold space already contains lines and the current line contains `}`, print those lines and start afresh with the current line. At the end of the file, swap back to the hold space (if it is not empty) and insert `content` before `}`.

Comment: ```sed -z 's/\(.*\)}/\1content}/' my.json > a.json```It works fine.  I seem to have discovered a new world.  wow! Thank you!